# 'Unable to get local issuer certificate' when accessing mongodb over ssl with certificate obtained by signing certificates with ACME server

Tags: mongodb, ssl, lets-encrypt

I created a SSL certificate valid for the domain `myapp.mydomain.com` using dehydrated https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated which uses the ACME protocol.

I have set this up on my mongodb server on my cloud. When I try to access the mongo server like this `mongo myapp.mydomain.com:27018  --ssl` from my local machine (where the certificate was generated), it works fine.

However, when I try the same command from `mongo:4` docker container, I get this error

```
root@ab9690f43a22:/# mongo myapp.mydomain.com:27018 -ssl
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://myapp.mydomain.com:27018/test?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-02-13T04:28:28.957+0000 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
2019-02-13T04:28:28.958+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server myapp.mydomain.com:27018, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I am not able to understand why it works on my local machine and does not work in the container. Probably, CA is not trusted?

also, I don't have the ca.pem file. I have attached the list of files that were generated.
[image]